# Android Retrofit Unable to parse data Rss feed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Hi im unable to parse data
here is base url https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/51120/rss.xml/

here is my code -->

```
  @GET("/api.json")
fun getNewTestFeeds(@Query( "rss_url") query :String) : Response<List<Model>>

companion object{
    val BASEURL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/"
  rss_url=http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/"
    var retrofitService : RetrofitService? = null
    fun getInstance(): RetrofitService{
        if (retrofitService ==null){
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASEURL)
              .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
        }
        return retrofitService!!
    }
}
```

and my repository

```
suspend fun  getTestFeeds() = 
retrofitService.getAllFeeds("http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/51120/rss.xml")
```

and my viewmodel

```
 fun getAllFeeds(){
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        loading.postValue(true)
        val response = mainRepository.getTestFeeds()//getAllFeeds()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                feedList.postValue(response.body())
                loading.value = false
            }else
                Log.i(TAG, "getAllFeeds:" +
                        " ${response.message()} and ${response.body().toString()}" +
                        " errorbody ${response.errorBody().toString()}")
            onError("Error :response.message()}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request returns JsonObject not array so it's should not be list.

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "feed": {
        "url": "http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/51120/rss.xml",
        "title": "Just In",
        "link": "https://www.abc.net.au/news/justin/",
        "author": "",
        "description": "",
        "image": "https://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8413416-1x1-144x144.png"
    },
    "items": [{}]
}
```

so declare your response class like below

```
class ResponseClass{

val status : String
val feed : YourFeedModel 
val items : List<YourItemModel>
}
```

And request  should be

```
@GET("/api.json")
fun getNewTestFeeds(@Query( "rss_url") query :String) : Response<ResponseClass>
```

Comment: How i can parse it as Response<List<Class>>

Comment: why you need list of objects ? just replace     `feedList.postValue(response.body())` by     `feedList.postValue(response.body().items)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("/api.json")
fun getNewTestFeeds(@Query( "rss_url") query :String) : Response<List<Model>>
```

The response from the api is an object but you are expecting the list.

Use https://www.json2kotlin.com/ to generate the data class from the json and follow the response structure. It should be just `Response<SomeModel>` not `Response<List<Model>>`

Comment: This it still not working

Comment: Whats the error that is shown?

Comment: also please add the data classes you are using

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:349)

Comment: Are you still using `Response<List<Model>>` ? please add your data classes

Answer (score 0):

First according on your response from api your response start with object not array
then your serializable is wrong

```
  @GET("/api.json")
 fun getNewTestFeeds(@Query( "rss_url") query :String) : Response<List<Model>>
```

this class of object response

```
data class ResponseClass(val status : String,val feed : YourFeedModel,   val items : List<YourItemModel>)
```

so your function   `getNewTestFeeds`  like this

```
   @GET("/api.json")
   fun getNewTestFeeds(@Query( "rss_url") query :String) : 
   Response<ResponseClass>
```

then move repository file you use wrong name of method you must call this method
like this

```
suspend fun  getTestFeeds() = 
retrofitService.getNewTestFeeds("http://www.abc.net.au/news/feed/51120/rss.xml")
```

then on viewModel you want set list on live data

```
 fun getAllFeeds(){
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    loading.postValue(true)
    val response = mainRepository.getTestFeeds()//getAllFeeds()
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            feedList.postValue(response.body().items)  // response.body() return class response you can get list from class to set it on livedata
            loading.value = false
        }else
            Log.i(TAG, "getAllFeeds:" +
                    " ${response.message()} and ${response.body().toString()}" +
                    " errorbody ${response.errorBody().toString()}")
        onError("Error :response.message()}")
    }
}
}
```